# SQL Server: generate empty row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Greeting all.

I have a SQL Server 2008 Express database with a table called `tbl_Sales`, similar as following:

```
Merchant | Sales |  Month
Comp.1      100     201101
Comp.1      200     201102
Comp.2      130     201102
Comp.1      250     201103
Comp.2      130     201103
Comp.3      240     201103
             .
             .
             .
Comp.3      340     201111
Comp.2      240     201112
Comp.3      140     201112
```

I want to generate the following data in MVC3 chart.

But the chart need all merchants' data every months else it will conflict.

So is there a way for SQL to do the result as following:

```
Merchant | Sales |  Month
Comp.1      100     201101
Comp.2        0     201101
Comp.3        0     201101
Comp.1      200     201102
Comp.2      130     201102
Comp.3        0     201102
Comp.1      250     201103
Comp.2      130     201103
Comp.3      240     201103
             .
             .
             .
Comp.3      340     201111
Comp.1        0     201112
Comp.2      240     201112
Comp.3      140     201112
```

We can have another table `tbl_Merchant` list out all the Merchant we need as following:

```
Merchant 
Comp.1
Comp.2
Comp.3
  .
  .
  .
Comp.10
```

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - do a cartesian join of Merchants to Months to be reported (so that you get each month row for every merchant), then left join to your data table - like so:

```
select mth.[Month], mct.Merchant, coalesce(s.Sales,0) Sales
from (select distinct [Month] from tbl_Sales) mth
cross join Merchant mct
left join tbl_Sales s 
       on mth.[Month] = s.[Month] and mct.Merchant = s.Merchant
```

(If tbl_Sales is particularly large, it might be quicker to populate the `mth` inline view with the necessary range of months from a recursive CTE-generated list of months, rather than selecting the necessary set of months from the Sales data.)